# Help with creating custom shortcut

Tags: unity, shortcuts, customization, emesene

I am using Emesene and when i click on the close bottom it does not quit the messenger which is great it goes into the mail icon on the top panel and i can open it again with clicking on the emesene icon, how can i create a custom shortcut to open the running emesene again? instead of clicking it

Edit: i mean i could press "Super + E" to open the main emesene window again just like if i clicked on the icon inside the mail icon on the top panel and don't open a new emesene window so i have to login again.

Comment: ON emesene>Preferences>Extensions>Tray icon select Indicator.

Answer (score 1):

In 11.10 and before open System Settings from the gear icon in the upper right. Select Keyboard, Shortcuts tab and then Custom Shortcuts on the bottom of the panel. In the bottom of the window you'll see a "+" key, click it. In the Name: field enter what you wish for a label. In the Command: field enter emesene and click the apply button. Select the the new line above with your label and click the word Disabled. New shortcut... will replace the word Disabled. Now enter the key activator and it will replace New shortcut.... "Super+E" will indicate "Mod4+E" and your done. If your keyboard shortcut doesn't work it's because it's already taken by the system. Super+E will work, I tried it.

As of 12.04 you can still create a custom short with the Super key but it won't work. A workable alternative for the example above is Ctrl+Alt+E.

Comment: Really ? I tried on both unity & unity-2d , all super related keys don't work for me .. odd , since when you press super , no matter a quick hit or slow hit , unity always take the control

Comment: Correct you are, apparently as of 12.04 the Super key is no longer a good choice for keyboard shortcuts. My answer which was valid for 11.10 has been edited to reflect that.